# How does a stored procedure handle index?

Tags: t-sql

Does a stored procedure use newly created indexes? I have a table which is dropped and recreated every time before the execution of the procedure. Does I have to recompile the procedure or does it use the new index and execution plan?

Sp_recompile

Comment: Why the overhead for drop and recreate?  Why not truncate table?

Comment: I don't know actually. I Will find out why....

Answer (score 1):

If you drop and recreate an object on which the stored procedure depends the stored procedure will be recompiled automatically and potentially use any new indexes that have been created.